# How do I set the areaStroke and areaFill properties of an AreaSeries using ActionScript?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3

In Flex the AreaSeries tag looks like this:

```
<mx:AreaSeries 
    yField="Profit" 
    displayName="Profit" 
    areaStroke="{s1}" 
    areaFill="{sc1}"
/>
```

I am creating an AreaChart dynamically using ActionScript and I want to set the areaStroke and areaFill properties but they don't appear to be available in ActionScript.

So my question is, how do I set these properties dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

areaStroke and areaFill are styles, not properties of the AreaSeries.

In actionscript you would have to do something like this:

```
myAreaSeries.setStyle("areaStroke",new SolidColorStroke());
myAreaSeries.setStyle("areaFill",new LinearGradient());
```

Check out the docs for [mx.graphics.IStroke](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/graphics/IStroke.html) to see what your options are and check the constructors for those classes to see what all you can set.